# Hibernate for Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-oxygen

I don't find the Hibernate plugin for the last version of my IDE, anyone knows is it's possible that Hibernate last version(5.2.2) is not compatible with Oxygen?

Comment: Hibernate is just a Java library. It doesn't need to be compatible with IDEs. It's just a jar in the classpath.

Comment: I solved the problem yesterday, but i forgot to close the question, sorry.